# liferay integration with EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, liferay

I am a Beginner in Liferay and I'm interested in it. I want to integrate Liferay with EC2. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.dunnsolutions.com/content/application-development-blog/-/blogs/liferay-6-x-integration-with-amazon-ec2) up to **Step 7** and I don't know how should I configure the portlet with the access and secret key. Can any one help me?

Comment: Hi Krzysztof Gołębiowski, thank you for edit. can you help me in my problem?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't deployed Liferay on EC2 yet :/